# How to install Gazebo to use along with ROS2 Humble Hawksbill on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gazebo, ros-humble

I have used ROS noetic before by installing the full desktop version which comes along with gazebo simulator and its plug-ins (gazebo_ros_pkgs) ready to use with ROS directly. Due to some requirements, I have to install ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04 on a cloud/ virtual machine. I decided to move with ROS2 Humble Hawksbill because as per https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases.html, this release will be supported for a longer period of time compared to Foxy which will have its EOL next year. [image]

I followed all the installation instructions present on their official website and did the full install using `sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop`. Publisher/ subscriber, rviz, rqt etc. are working fine but I observed that gazebo did not come along with it.

I am having a tough time figuring out a way to install gazebo and make it work with ROS2 Humble Hawksbill on Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried going through https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros2_installing&cat=connect_ros, https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/ros2_integration, and https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-2-humble-hawksbill-released/25729 and observed that one website is saying something and another something else regarding ros2 and gazebo versions compatibility.

Any help in setting up gazebo (which version and how) in this scenario is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Dev

Answer (score 3):

Gazebo is part of `desktop-full` not the `desktop` variant.

You can use `ros-humble-simulation` as a convenient metapackage as well.

The metapackages are defined as variants in [REP 2001 (Humble)](https://ros.org/reps/rep-2001.html#humble-hawksbill-may-2022-ongoing)

Comment: I tried to send `sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop-full` but it says `E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop-full`

Comment: I think I found the issue. My cloud machine architecture is `arm64` which I found using `dpkg-architecture -q DEB_BUILD_ARCH`. Then, I tried to compare the packages list manually by browsing the OSU website itself. 
[amd64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages . This one contains `ros-humble-desktop-full` but [arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages does not. Maybe, that's why I am getting unable to locate package error.

Comment: On arm64 there are a few dependencies which were not available at release time. The maintainers are working on rebuilding them at the moment. And they will hopefully be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

There *was* a question about installing Gazebo on Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble (after removing the copy installed with the Humble package install), on the Gazebo answers page, see [How to install Gazebo for Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28361/how-to-install-gazebo-for-ubuntu-2204-with-ros2-humble/). Unfortunately, that content has now been removed (as of July 31 2022), for whatever reason.

However, there is a blog on Ubuntu.com, [Install Gazebo for ROS 2 in under a minute](https://ubuntu.com/blog/install-gazebo-for-ros-2-in-under-a-minute), which *might* help.

> With the option `--channel`, we are explicitly using the track (citadel) and the risk (beta). We will automatically get updates from this channel. If your Linux distribution of choice doesn’t currently support snap, get more details on the [installing snapd documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd?_ga=2.40975083.853092938.1659281209-1493036531.1650009436).
>
> ```
> sudo snap install gazebo --channel=citadel/beta
> ```
>
> After installation, we can execute the freshly installed Gazebo with the command `gazebo.gz gazebo`.

You can then test it with

> ```
> gazebo.gz gazebo shapes.sdf
> ```
>
> We now see the ‘shapes’ demo
> and are able to interact with it:
>
> [image]

There are a lot more examples. ***However, none of this is Humble specific***.

Nevertheless, that same page then states at the bottom:

> We are planning to release a ROS2 Humble Gazebo Fortress snap soon, so stay tuned!

So, hopefully, there should be an update (and accompanying blog) available soon...

Comment: Thanks! I can't recall is exactly but I somehow managed to install/ build it from source.

Comment: Why does this not open with ```gazebo``` why does it need ```gazebo.gz gazebo``` ?

Comment: @Frank - I'm not entirely sure, but I would guess that it is because the binary has been compiled with the name `gazebo.gz` rather than just `gazebo` - possibly to avoid any conflict with any existing binary named `gazebo`. Note that this is purely a guess of my part... As stated in my answer, I merely copied the details from the [Ubuntu gazebo blog](https://ubuntu.com/blog/install-gazebo-for-ros-2-in-under-a-minute). Read that blog for more details.